# Are any of the characters in Danger Club from other comics?

Tags: comics, danger-club, image-comics

[Danger Club](https://imagecomics.com/comics/series/danger-club) stars a bunch of sidekicks having to take over superheroing after their heroes all died/disappeared after going into space to fight some unspecified menace.

**Are any of the characters in the comic from (existing) other comics, given the omnipresent cross-pollination that seems to happen?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The characters portrayed were original creations for the Danger Club comic serial.

> **AiPT:** *Where did you decide to draw the line on your characters acting as pastiches for Marvel/DC personas while also functioning as
> unique individuals? Was the parody aspect a tool to get readers to
> superficially identify with your characters out of the gate, before
> reading on and finding out that their personalities run counter to the
> more famous hero they’re modeled after?*
>
> **Landry:** ***It was definitely a conscious angle to use and reinvent familiar archetypes as a shortcut to gain reader understanding.** We
> didn’t want to tell a dozen origin stories right out the gate – though
> all of our main characters origin stories are slowly disseminated in
> tiny bites through the course of the series.*
>
> <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW WITH ‘DANGER CLUB’ CREATOR LANDRY Q. WALKER](http://www.adventuresinpoortaste.com/2015/03/12/interview-with-danger-club-creator-landry-q-walker/)</sup></sub>

and

> **CA:** *So you wanted to give people the sense that you were ruining their childhood, but **with characters they’d never read before.***
>
> **LW:** *Exactly.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Landry Walker And Eric Jones On The Return Of 'Danger Club'](http://comicsalliance.com/landry-q-walker-eric-jones-danger-club-interview/)</sup></sub>

That being said, these characters were clearly intended as 'pastiches' of existing DC/Marvel sidekicks, obviating the need to tell an 'origin story' for each one since readers could simply assume that their origin is much the same as the character they're based on.

> **Q. You of course utilize teen-hero archetypes and analogs extensively, although some are more easily identifiable than others: For instance,
> Kid Vigilante/Robin and Jack Fearless/Bucky Barnes. Was there a
> process for deciding which analogs the story required – was it, “OK,
> we need a Robin and a John/Zachary Zatara,” or did the characters’
> personalities and roles develop first?**
>
> **Landry Walker:** ***The roles came first. Most of the characters are analogous for people we have known – mostly during our teen years. Some of whom are long
> lost through sickness, suicide or accident. Some of the superhero
> analogs were intentional, and others were coincidental.** Bucky was
> actually not intended at first, but morphed naturally into the role as
> we developed the story. He was originally a guy with luck powers who
> had managed to have most of his body destroyed and survived to be
> rebuilt into a robot form. It wasn’t until after we developed the
> American Spirit that we placed Jack in that Bucky-esque role.*
>
> <sub><sup>[LANDRY WALKER ON THE ‘LIBERATING’ RETURN OF ‘DANGER CLUB’](http://www.cbr.com/landry-walker-on-the-liberating-return-of-danger-club/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

After sustained hunting for the "heroes" of this series the answer appears to be no, all the sidekicks are unique inventions for the Danger Club series.  However some of the sidekicks appear to pay homage to well-known sidekicks from other series.